# Gradle error with Android-studio and googleMap api

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, build.gradle

I created a simple project to test Google Api under android studio , but I have this error I tried to correct it by adding maps.jar to librairies of project structure no way :

```
    Information:Compilation completed with 12 errors and 0 warnings in 17 sec
Information:12 errors
Information:0 warnings
/home/phenix-dz/AndroidStudioProjects/Geolocalisation/Geolocalisation/src/main/java/com/example/geolocalisation/MainActivity.java
    Error:Error:line (4)Gradle: error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
    Error:Error:line (5)Gradle: error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
    Error:Error:line (6)Gradle: error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
    Error:Error:line (9)Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class MapActivity
    Error:Error:line (11)Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class MapView
    Error:Error:line (12)Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class MapController
    Error:Error:line (16)Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable super
    Error:Error:line (17)Gradle: error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)
    Error:Error:line (19)Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class MapView
    Error:Error:line (19)Gradle: error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
    Error:Error:line (14)Gradle: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    Error:Error:line (25)Gradle: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

also I tried to add this code :

```
apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile files('/home/phenix-dz/android-studio/sdk/add-ons/google_apis-671458-mac-x86/libs/maps.jar')

}
```

in build.gradle file but it gives me a same error.

Thanks

Comment: I found it , it was just adding dependencies in wrong build.gradle file ... I think that it still a greate work to do to learn Android studio structure project.